# Error creating a dataframe from a csv file

Tags: r

Error: `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 1 did not have 2 elements`

My file structure:

```
codigo  descricao
101     Oficiais generais das forças armadas
102     Oficiais das forças armadas
201     Oficiais superiores da polícia militar
203     Tenentes da polícia militar
211     Subtenentes e sargentos da policia militar
212     Cabos e soldados da polícia militar
301     Oficiais superiores do corpo de bombeiros militar
312     Cabos e soldados do corpo de bombeiros militar
1111    Legisladores
1112    Dirigentes gerais da administração pública
1113    Magistrados
2103    ...............
3156    ...............
```

Code:

```
cbo2002_familia <- read.table("CBO2002_Familia.csv",sep=";",
                    header = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8", col.names = c("codigo, descricao"),  colClasses = c("factor", "character"))
```

I need to import this CSV file, with these two HEADERS, to manipulate it. But I came across this error and I can not understand why. If you do not specify the columns and type of each column, the import is done normally.
How to proceed?

I want to specify as factor and character, so that the code column, fill with a 0 (zero) in front of the items that has only 3 numbers.

Comment: It seems ir should   be sep = " "

Comment: In read.table("CBO2002_Familia.csv", sep = "", header = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8",  :
  header and 'col.names' are of different lengths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that your separator is a tab `\t`.

`col.names = c("codigo, descricao")` should be `col.names = c("codigo", "descricao")`

```
cbo2002_familia <- read.table("CBO2002_Familia.csv",sep="\t",
                 header=T, encoding = "UTF-8", col.names = c("codigo", "descricao"),  colClasses = c("factor", "character"))

head(cbo2002_familia)
#  codigo                                  descricao
#1    101       Oficiais generais das forças armadas
#2    102                Oficiais das forças armadas
#3    201     Oficiais superiores da polícia militar
#4    203                Tenentes da polícia militar
#5    211 Subtenentes e sargentos da policia militar
#6    212        Cabos e soldados da polícia militar
```

Comment: Without specifying col.names, I was actually able to import the data. But the columns have strange names. Thanks for the help and I will follow this way. My sep was ";"

Comment: @Henrique You made a typo - missed some `"` when defining `col.names`.